# How can be sum number of data in the same column for specific condition in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by, sum

```
book1_part1       1   00000118323
book1_part1       1   00000118323
book1_part1       1   00000118323
book1_part1       1   00000118323
book1_part1       2   00000118323
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       2   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118337
book1_part1       1   00000118343
```

every book have id and this id have numbers of copies ,
so the database is looking like above and the result should be  :

```
book1_part1  00000118323 have 6 copies 
book1_part1  00000118337 have 8 copies 
book1_part1  00000118343 have 1 copy
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using, MySQL or Oracle? Only tag the one you're really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query.

Assuming that the table is called `books` and that its columns are named `name`, `id`  and `no_copies`, you would go:

```
select name, id, sum(no_copies) total_no_copies
from books
group by name, id
```

You can easily generate the expected phrase using string concatenation - although this task would be better suited for your application:

```
select 
    name, 
    concat(
        id, 
        ' has ',
        sum(no_copies),
        case when sum(no_copies) = 1 then ' copy' else ' copies' end
    ) info
from books
group by name, id
```

Comment: Super , it is working perfect, can i add condition that it will show me just the id and book which have more than 4 copies ?

Comment: @PythonP: just add `having sum(no_copies) > 4` at the end of the query.